# Try to get USSD response in android

Tags: android

I want to find a way to get response from USSD Codes.

I've already found these links [Implementing USSD features. Binding a service to the PhoneUtils without restarting the phone on every update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722178/android-implementing-ussd-features-binding-a-service-to-the-phoneutils-withou)
 and
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iba.ussdchecker&hl=en.I found so many related questions about getting USSD response but there was no complete answers for questions.

I am using Sony Ericsson Xperia Ray.I only found the pop up message on the phone screen. 
I didn't get any response code from background.

Comment: You can try to decompile one of the Apps you find in Google Play and see if you find there right in there.

Comment: Check this answer out. It may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594250/ussd-service-not-working/12707480#12707480

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no universal solution. It was restricted due to security reasons.