# Popup a dialog with ussd code in android

Tags: android, ussd

I'm trying to add some features to my android application with `USSD` codes. assume when user type `*#12345#` on home screen in my app. then i need to show a dialog or send user to a another screen in my app.

how can i accomplish this task ?

Comment: just compare the USSD code with your own USSD code format

Comment: @itsrajesh4uguys how to enable dial pad for my app and how to detect user entered USSD code ?

Comment: Intent dial = new Intent();
dial.setAction("android.intent.action.DIAL");
dial.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+dial_number));
startActivity(dial);

Comment: your edit text input type will be    android:inputType="phone"

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594250/ussd-service-not-working

Answer (score 1):

Try following code.

**ussd_layout.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And your `MainActivity.java` will have following code

```
package com.example.ussdcodetest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class USSDTestActivity extends Activity {

TextView txt;
RelativeLayout rel;
String s = "";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ussdtest);

    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    rel = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative);

    txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("USSD", "CLICKED");
            ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
                    .toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,
                            InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_ussdtest, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    Log.d("USSD", "Key Down  :" + keyCode + " String : " + s);
    s += (char) event.getUnicodeChar();

    if (s.equals("action")) {
        Toast.makeText(USSDTestActivity.this, "Action will be performed",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
                .hideSoftInputFromWindow(rel.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
}
```

What my code will do is, it will take input from keyboard which will be shown on `TextView`'s click event, and when input will be matched with **action** word, it will hide keyboard and `Toast` message on screen. You can write your own code inside that if condition.

**Note:** There must be some action to show or hide keyboard on activity, that is why I use `onClickEvent` of `TextView`. You can use as per your need. Best idea is use `Gesture`.