# Android USSD reply Saving

Tags: android, ussd

I did many R&D to get the reply from USSD from my app.
But after that I can request fot USSD but not abl to get response to my app.

Is there any solution go get the reply from USSD.

Thanks

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594250/ussd-service-not-working

Answer (score 4):

In short you need to create an `AIDL` file that exposes some methods to use the android intent `com.android.ussd.IExtendedNetworkService`

Look a this blog post that explains how to intercept USSD response message, it is very helpful for your case. [Intercepting USSD calls in Android](http://www.codedemigod.com/intercepting-ussd-calls-in-android/)

Comment: Can you pleaase give me an example how to use that servise?:(

Comment: @Majid : From the link I've posted in this answer, here is a complete sample code from the author : [SampleCode](https://github.com/alaasalman/ussdinterceptor)

Comment: Thanks for your help but I cant use that project in mine,I tried to google abut that project and how to use it but cant find anything :(

Comment: @Majid what is exactly the problem you are facing? here is another project that you can read to help you implement your solution. it is in russian, in the bottom of the page before the comments section, provide name and email and click on the button to download the source code [Project link](http://commandus.com/blog/?p=45)

Comment: @YasmineGreenApple i am getting error for ussd cant response message after calling "*112#"

Comment: @AndoMasahashi unfortunately this method does not work in the latest versions of android (4.0+) due to the removal of the IExtendedNetworkService

Comment: @YasmineGreenApple so can i test it on below (4.0) an is there any solution ?