# How to get USSD Response in android 4.2.2 and above

Tags: android

I am currently working on an application to process balance information comes in USSD response. For this purpose I was using IExtendedNetworkService and took help from:

https://github.com/alaasalman/ussdinterceptor

It is not working for android 4.2.2 and above and after lots of searching i came to know that it has been removed from 4.2.2 and above due to security issues. I further read a related post in which no one replied:

[A new way to manage USSD dialogs in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875914/a-new-way-to-manage-ussd-dialogs-in-android)

So my question is same that is there anyway to get ussd response for android 4.2.2 and above? if yes then kindly suggest me the way... thanx