# Auto USSD Code dial from Java Android

Tags: java, android

I try to Develop an Android App For Auto Dial USSD code from Java Program

**Example** When I Dial *121# Here response

```
Menu: 1 Facebook
        2 Sports
        3 Jokes
```

[Screen Short one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoKM7.jpg)

When I Enter 2 and Click Send Button Here Show New Menu(After getting Response)

```
Menu: 1 Cricket
        2 Football
```

Then  I Enter 2 And Click Send Button and Football Service Active.

Now I want to Active football Service Auto from App By Auto Dial *121# And Auto Replay Menu Response  First 2 Then 2

Note: Short Code Not Working (*121*1*2#) By Dialing

Please Help me How to do it?

Comment: Why don't you visit this page? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875914/a-new-way-to-manage-ussd-dialogs-in-android

Comment: i visit the page but but not help it