# How do I detect when user closes ussd dialog in Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm running ussd code from my code. After it returns the results the user will press the ok button to close the the dialog. I want to detect when the user does this.

Comment: show your code.

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/34132003

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that this is your dialog code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
    builder.setTitle("dialog's title");
    builder.setMessage("dialogs's text");
    builder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //do stuff when user presses ok button
        }
    });
    builder.setNeutralButton("CANCEL", null); //same here just add the listener
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
//you can use neutralButton as well
```